# Interpreting OBD2 services and characteristics Swift4

Tags: swift, bluetooth-lowenergy, swift4, core-bluetooth, obd-ii

I am creating an application that connects to a VEEPEAK BLE device that reads vehicle metrics such as MPH, RPM and other properties.  I am able to connect to the device using CoreBluetooth and am able to see the devices Services and characteristics.  My problem is i cannot find any documentation or GAAT table that references these codes.  Below is a print out of my console to show the various UUID's i am discovering.

```
Optional("VEEPEAK") has service with uuid 180A
Optional("VEEPEAK") has service with uuid 49535343-FE7D-4AE5-8FA9- 
9FAFD205E455
Optional("VEEPEAK") has service with uuid FFF0
service with uuid 180A has characteristic with uuid 2A29
service with uuid 180A has characteristic with uuid 2A24
service with uuid 180A has characteristic with uuid 2A25
service with uuid 180A has characteristic with uuid 2A27
service with uuid 180A has characteristic with uuid 2A26
service with uuid 180A has characteristic with uuid 2A28
service with uuid 180A has characteristic with uuid 2A23
service with uuid 180A has characteristic with uuid 2A2A
service with uuid 49535343-FE7D-4AE5-8FA9-9FAFD205E455 has 
characteristic with uuid 49535343-6DAA-4D02-ABF6-19569ACA69FE
service with uuid 49535343-FE7D-4AE5-8FA9-9FAFD205E455 has 
characteristic with uuid 49535343-ACA3-481C-91EC-D85E28A60318
service with uuid FFF0 has characteristic with uuid FFF1
service with uuid FFF0 has characteristic with uuid FFF2
```

How can i interpret these codes to retrieve the information i am seeking?

Comment: This kind of characteristics/Services with UUID starting with `49535343-` ( 32 hex instead of 4) are custom. It's up to the one that develop them to share its doc or not. If you still want to find them, ask the developer, or do some reverse engineering.

Comment: What about the 180A and FFF0? What makes those different from the 49535343?

Comment: They are officials and documented (it's like following a protocol) by the Bluetooth Consortium. See there: https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/services In theory, if you want to have yours custom in your device, you should use a 32 hex UUID for it, saying to anyone connecting to it that it's custom.

Comment: I see, so im guessing the information i want is in 49535343-.  Considering the other 2 services are just device information such as model number and serial number.  Like you said, my best bet would be to dig into 49535343- and see if i can make some sense of its properties correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying.

Comment: Please see the answer I have given @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52075456/which-gatt-profile-and-services-are-used-by-obd-ble-adapters-like-lelink-automa/52139765#52139765